# Dynamically updating date in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to create a dynamically updating date in Excel.

Right now in Cell A1 I have the text "updated through"
In B1 I have the formula =Today()-1.

I join them with (&) in C1. The problem is that it is displayed as "updated through 43514" I've tried formatting the cell as a date (ie 2/19/2019) but it won't work. How can I do this, or is it even possible?

Comment: Can you show the exact (full) formula in C1?  That would be easiest for us to give you a 100% functional change that should drag down to all cells effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=A1 & TEXT(B1, "mm/dd/yy")`

---

*Make sure cell `A1` has a lagging space or you can add `CHAR(32)` in the middle of the above equation*